How to prevent a screen reader from reading content twice?
I have a carousel that scrolls horizontally. Each item in the carousel has an image from an instagram post and some details from the post such as caption, the user and date. The whole item is clickable, which will open a modal to the product in the post.
When using a screen reader (VoiceOver) it focuses on the item card, announces all the content and then proceeds to focus on each individual child element and reads them aloud again. Note that this only happens when the screen reader is auto reading through content on the page. If I control the focus myself it doesn't do this. It only reads all the content when focus is on the parent and then it stops. When I press tab it moves to the next item.
Is this expected behaviour for screen readers? I have tried to research this but kind of coming up short. I feel like it would cause issues for users and I'm open to ideas on how to correct this to comply with WCAG 2.0 guidelines.
I'm trying to achieve the content being read once when the parent is focused only. I have tried adding tabindex="-1" and aria-hidden="true" to the child elements. Tabindex didn't do anything for me and aria-hidden stopped the elements from being announced on the parent element too.
This is my structure, I have left out styling classes for simplicity
<div class="Parent__item" tabindex="0">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media__container">
      <div class="media__fallback"></div>
      <img src="https://filepath" alt="content-element">
    </div>  
    <div class="media__overlay">
      <div class="overlay__content">
        <div>
          <i class="instagram-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="content-element">Shop Now</div>
        <div>
          <div class="content-element">user</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-element">3 years ago</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


CAn you post a link to a test page ? Thank you.

Since the question generalises the behaviour screen readers, I like to point out that SR are not all behaving the same! The question can help figure out if VoiceOver is expected to show this behaviour. Btw is this VO on macOS or on iOS? There are big differences as well.
